# How to solve these issues installing OIS?

Tags: compiling, c++

I am trying to install OIS on Ubuntu 13.10 because I am trying to install orgre because I am trying to install FreeOrion. Anyway, here is the page I am following: [link](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1148570) which fails in step 1.1 at the 'make' step with the following error message:

```
./linux/LinuxJoyStickEvents.cpp: In member function 'virtual void OIS::LinuxJoyStick::capture()':
./linux/LinuxJoyStickEvents.cpp:100:77: error: 'read' was not declared in this scope
   int ret = read(mJoyStick, &js, sizeof(struct input_event) * JOY_BUFFERSIZE);
                                                                             ^
./linux/LinuxJoyStickEvents.cpp: In static member function 'static OIS::JoyStickInfoList OIS::LinuxJoyStick::_scanJoys()':
./linux/LinuxJoyStickEvents.cpp:275:13: error: 'close' was not declared in this scope
     close(fd);
             ^
./linux/LinuxJoyStickEvents.cpp:283:12: error: 'close' was not declared in this scope
    close(fd);
            ^
./linux/LinuxJoyStickEvents.cpp: In static member function 'static void OIS::LinuxJoyStick::_clearJoys(OIS::JoyStickInfoList&)':
./linux/LinuxJoyStickEvents.cpp:294:20: error: 'close' was not declared in this scope
   close(i->joyFileD);
                    ^
make[1]: *** [LinuxJoyStickEvents.lo] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/alexander/opt/src/ois-v1-3/src'
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

How can I fix this problem? Maybe there is a way to install `ois` with `apt-get`, or even to install `orgre` with `apt.get` directly without the 'configure/make/make install' detour?

Comment: Have you checked the requirements for this program? This could be due to a compiler or a library that's too old.

Answer (score 1):

**In short:** It's available via `apt-get` with:

```
 sudo apt-get install libois-dev
```

and/or

```
 sudo apt-get install libois-1.3.0
```

**In long:**
Based on all the warnings in the boot strap and configure I think it's just a wee bit old. 
The [repo](https://github.com/wgois/Object-oriented-Input-System--OIS-) has not been touched in 5 years or so although there are some forks.

As for install ogre via apt this is also possible, but it is an older version. It's available via the ppa [ppa:ogre-team/ogre](https://launchpad.net/~ogre-team/+archive/ubuntu/ogre)